# How do i save model data when creating a Backbone driven theme in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, backbone.js

Ok so im messing around with Backbone for the first time. I think I've pretty much covered all the **basics** of frontend logic, but i have never really been any good at backend logic and coding.

I'm working with wordpress and creating a theme using backbone. My understanding is as long as i set up a template page that has the correct containers that my backbone code will render views in, the fact that it's a wordpress theme instead of it's own app shouldn't really change anything on the frontend side.

I'm at the stage where i want to save a model so that i can fetch it in my routes to link to my view to render.

I'm unsure about the whole process of saving data. I know i need to give the model attribute 'urlRoot' a string but i don't know what that string should be, and what happens after that.

Can someone explain the whole process, especially in terms of how to do it with Wordpress. (i did stumble upon the WP REST API plugin that i think helps, although i don't exactly know how.)

**EDIT**

OK so in the end i presume my problem was something to do with authentication when trying to access the database as the textResponse was just returning the entire HTML for the current page i was on, probably due to the fact it wasn't getting through to the database and being redirected back to the page.

After googling around for a while i came across [this](https://github.com/WP-API/client-js). Rather than reinventing the wheel I installed this plugin and followed the setup instructions and low and behold it worked pretty much out of the box. If your trying to build a Backbone theme i suggest using the WP-API Client JS plugin with the WP REST API plugin. Seems to cover everything.

Comment: I added the linked plugin to my answer to let readers easily find it. I encourage you to accept an answer or make your own to mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

## How to expose a WordPress blog's content through an API?

[**WP REST API**](http://v2.wp-api.org/) seems like a good way to start. There are a lot of options and it exposes everything you need.

Note that it is named [**WordPress REST API (Version 2)**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) in the [wordpress.org plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).

You can test that the plugin works by navigating to:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/
```

It should output all the information on the blog as a big JSON dump.

You can also test that it works for other endpoints, like post:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

There's a [Backbone plugin for the WP REST API](https://github.com/WP-API/client-js) that works out of the box.

## How to communicate with the API?

*This is a simple example using Backbone without any plugin. If you want to know how to use the plugin, see [the documentation](https://github.com/WP-API/client-js) for it.*

Since it offers a lot of arguments that can be passed in the URL, I made a small collection and an example of how it could be used.

```
var API_ROOT = '/wp-json/wp/v2/',
    DEFAULT_API_ARGS = ['context' /* etc. */ ];

var WordPressCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    constructor: function(models, options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.apiArgs = _.union(DEFAULT_API_ARGS, this.apiArgs, options.apiArgs);
        this.args = _.extend({}, this.args, this.getApiArgs(options));

        WordPressCollection.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    getApiArgs: function(obj) {
        return _.pick(obj, this.apiArgs);
    },

    fetch: function(options) {
        options = options || {};
        options.data = _.extend({}, this.args, this.getApiArgs(options), options.data);
        return WordPressCollection.__super__.fetch.call(this, options);
    },
});
```

And to use it:

```
var CommentCollection = WordPressCollection.extend({
    url: API_ROOT + 'comments',
    // all the arguments to look for in the passed options
    apiArgs: ['page', 'per_page', 'post' /* etc. */ ],
});

var myPostComments = new CommentCollection(null, {
    post: 23 // id
});

console.log(myPostComments.url());

myPostComments.fetch({ page: 2 });
```

The `fetch` should make a `GET` request to:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=23&page=2
```

And from that point, the WP REST API plugin takes control. It returns a new JSON encoded array of comment objects in the body of the response.

It should looks something like this:

[image: WP REST API comments response]

Backbone automatically parses the JSON received, so you don't need to worry about that and you just have to go on and use it:

```
myPostComments.each(function(comment) {
    console.log(comment.get('author_name'));
});
```

Then, saving a new comment is a matter of calling:

```
// check the doc for the comment object details
myPostComments.create({
    post: 23,
    content: "my new comment",
    /* etc. */
});
```

And this would make a `POST` request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/comments`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You answered my last question as well a few days ago and both times you've given really in depth answers. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm getting this error. GET http://backbonetest.localhost/wp/v2/comments?post=1&page=1 404 (Not Found). Looked in the database to make sure there's a post with ID = 1 and a comment on that post. Otherwise not sure how else I'm meant to debug this.

Comment: @matty 404 means the url is not correct. Check the plugin doc and also, I think you can try the url manually.

Comment: Ok realized the i was using version 1 of the WP REST API which is why it couldn't find the URL. Updated that but I'm still not getting anything. No error message but no data either. Console is logging nothing. I'm working with a fresh version of wordpress, copy and pasted your example, added a bunch of comments too the hello-word post, and passed in `post: 1` to the new collection object. Added this to the end of the fetch function ` myPostComments.fetch().done(alert(myPostComments.length));` and no matter what i do its just returning 0. Any ideas?

Comment: @MattyB I updated my answer to reflect the API root, which is `/wp-json/wp/v2/`.

Comment: Yea I realized that after messing around with it a bit, sorry for not mentioning it. That isn't my issue. I added an error callback to my fetch which it's hitting every time with a status of 200 and textStatus of 'OK'. I know that it could be a huge number of things but knowing I've copied your example, could you think of any reason why that's happening?

Comment: OK after further investigation the responseText is returning a whole page of HTML, rather than the JSON it's meant to be returning. Any idea why?

Comment: @MattyB if you navigate to `backbonetest.localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, do you see any JSON encoded posts?